# Como graficar un grafico de barras a partir de series en pandas python

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

tengo una duda sobre como graficar con una serie.

La cosa es que tengo un Dataframe que tiene artistas, anios, albumes etc...lo que yo queria hacer era saber cuantas veces estaba un artista en el Dataframe, entonces puse que me contara y me dio un resultado.

Ahora lo que quier hacer es que esa serie sea greficada, lo que pasa es que quiero ver la cantidad de veces que me aparece un artista (de acuerdo a la playlist pero que he separado en diferentes documentos para hacerlo paso a paso) pero lo quiero visualizar con barras. Pero no tengo idea de como hacerlo porque no he graficado series, solo listas. Esto es lo que llevo hasta ahora...

```
#frecuencias de Artistas en la primera playlist
frec_abs_artist1 = df1['Artist'].value_counts()
frec_abs_artist1
```

y me aparece como
artista 1      8
artista 2      4
artista 3      3

Como hago para representar el output en una barra de graficos?

Comment: igual te resulta más util usar [df.hist()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.hist.html)

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar la librería matplotlib.

Su uso inicial es sencillo:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt        # Importar la libreria

plt.style.use("bmh")                   # Elegir un tipo de estilo

plt.bar(series_x, series_y)            # Crear gráfico
plt.show()                             # Mostrar gráfico
plt.close('all')                       # Cerrar ventana
```

Un pequeño ejemplo, siguiendo el esquema que planteas:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt        # Importar la libreria

# Creas o importas de información de los artistas
datos = pd.DataFrame([['Wardruna','Gap var Ginnunga', 2009],['Sahg', 'I', 2006],['Jotunspor','Gleipnirs Smeder',2006],['Gorgoroth','Twilight of the idols', 2003],['Wardruna','Yggdrasil', 2013],['Sahg','Delussions of Grandeur',2013],['Gorgoroth','Black mass Krakow',2008], ['Wardruna','Ragnarok',2016], ['Sahg','Memento Mori',2016]], columns=['Artista', 'Album', 'Jahr'])

# Haces el conteo que necesitas, y guardas los datos en una variable, esta variable que se crea es de tipo:<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>    # type(variable)
conteo = datos['Artista'].value_counts()

# Elegir un tipo de estilo (opcional)
# Guía de estilos:
# https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/style_sheets/style_sheets_reference.html
plt.style.use("bmh")                   

# Envias los datos de la variable conteo para el eje x y el eje y
plt.bar(conteo.index, conteo)            # Crear gráfico
plt.show()                               # Mostrar gráfico
plt.close('all')                         # Cerrar ventana
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]